# Jquery mobile Is it possible to have an editable region?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I have a mobile page and I want the user to be able edit content on their profile. I have tried jquery jeditable but it does not work on mobile. I have the profile content placed inside a collapsible so I want user to click on region and then be able to update that region.

Is it possible to do on mobile ? Is there a way to do it with javascript ?

Here is my profile code:

```
<div data-collapsed="true" data-role="collapsible">
    <h3>
        <img height="20" src="images/jay.jpg" width="22"> Username
    </h3>
    <a class="" data-role="button" href="">Edit</a>

    <h4>About Me:</h4>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam dignissim
    mi a justo sollicitudin porttitor eu vi tae ipsum. Curabitur vitae auctor
    turpis. In volutpat consectetur elit, quis varius nisl dignissim in. Nunc
    in nunc vel elit fermentum fermentum non eu dolor. Vivamus euismod sapien
    ut augue euismod, sit amet malesuada odio pulvinar. Vivamus porttitor felis
    in eros mattis luctus. Maecenas ultricies ligula nec elementum gravida.</p>

    <h4>Skillsset:</h4>

    <p>Web, Logo Design, Business Cards, Graphic Design, Animation, Digital
    Marketing, User Interface Design, Banner Design, Posters, Signs</p>

    <h4>
        Contact No: 
        <a href="tel:555555">555555</a>
    </h4>
    <img height="50" src="images/james/jay1.jpg" width="55"> 
    <img height="50" src="images/jay2.jpg" width="55"> 
    <img height="50" src="images/jay3.jpg" width="55"> 
    <img height="50" src="images/jay4.jpg" width="55">
</div><!-- end of collaspible-->
```

So how would I go about allowing the user to click Skillset region for example and update the skills.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Can you use a textarea: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/textinput/#Textarea?

Comment: Yes but my problem remains how to edit/update the content within the textarea. Say my textarea already has text in it. I want to edit that text or update text.

Comment: As soon as you tap or click inside a textarea, the keyboard displays and you can edit the text. It is designed for text editing.

Comment: I understand now, thats not really the look or feel I am going for. But thanks for helping